# upload an image using retrofit with multipart

Tags: android, json, retrofit, multipart

I'm trying to upload an image along with a pojo model with username and password, but how do i use the multipart to add both, here is my code but isn't working:

```
EndpointInterface loginService = ServiceAuthGenerator.createService(EndpointInterface.class);
                RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
                Call<String> call = loginService.singup(requestBody,us);
                call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {@Override
                    public void onResponse(Response<String> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {                       
                    }
                });
```

us is my pojo model and it contains the user and the password.
this is the API interface:

```
    @Multipart
    @POST("reg/")
    Call<String> singup(
            @Part("myfile\"; filename=\"image.png\" ") RequestBody file,
            @Part("User") User user);
```

can anyone explain what im doing wrong and how to fix it please?

Answer (score 0):

Should you use `MediaType.parse("image/*")` instead `MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data")`? It is because you upload image later.

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off using the multipart builder for the request body than the @Multipart annotation.

```
    RequestBody body = new MultipartBuilder()
                                .type(MultipartBuilder.FORM)
                                .addFormDataPart("myFile", "image.png", RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpg"), new File(picture.getLocalPath())))                              
                                .addFormDataPart("user", gson.toJson(user))
                                .build();



 @POST("reg/")
 Call<String> singup(@Body RequestBody image);
```